# Set-Cookie was blocked on a dot net core application

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm getting the following error when setting a cookie:

> This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute is invalid
> with regards to the current host URL

In my angular application I'm using credentials on my http call:

```
 withCredentials: true
```

In my .net core application, I am setting the cookie as follows:

```
Response.Cookies.Append(id, "rememberDevice", new CookieOptions()
    {
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(2),
        Path = "/",
        HttpOnly = true,
        IsEssential = true,
        Domain = "http://localhost:5006",
    });
```

Here is my cookie response:

[image]

The exclamation triangle is what shows the error above.

What have I done wrong?

EDIT

I've tried changing the Domain to just "localhost:5006" but that has not worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If cookies are used only on localhost, it is not necessary to specify the domain attribute. It is safer not to.
If you really want to add the domain attribute, specify domain=localhost. The scheme (http://) and port number are unnecessary.